# Как выровнять картинку по центру?

Tags: joomla, html, css

Есть лого. Содержится внутри тега `h1`, принадлежащего классу `logo`.
В CSS у `#logo` стоит `text-align: left`, я его перегружаю в `#logo img`, пишу `text-align: center`. Даже в теге `img` прописываю `align="middle"`. Хоть бы хны, всё равно слева. Отладчики хрома и оперы показывают, что у изображения стоит свойство `text-align: center`.

На всякий случай, так выглядит рассчитанный стиль:

```
background-attachment: scroll;  
background-clip: border-box;  
background-color: #EEE;  
background-image: url(header_outer.jpg);  
background-origin: padding-box;  
color: #333;  
display: block;  
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size: 16px;  
height: 1133px;  
margin-bottom: 0px;  
margin-left: 0px;  
margin-right: 0px;  
margin-top: 0px;  
padding-bottom: 0px;  
padding-left: 0px;  
padding-right: 0px;  
padding-top: 0px;  
position: relative;  
text-align: center;  
width: 1263px;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил, поместив тег `img` в `<div align="center">`, ну или просто `<center>`, но это какой-то костыль.

Answer (score 5):

`text-align` не работает для изображений, это свойство выравнивает только текст. Чтобы выровнять что-либо, этому объекту нужно задать свойство `display:block;`, потом задать ему ширину `width: 1263px;` и в конце присвоить ему свойство `margin:0 auto;`.

Comment: вам прийдется убрать:
<code> 
margin-bottom: 0px;  
margin-left: 0px;  
margin-right: 0px;  
margin-top: 0px; 
position: relative;
</code>
иначе то что я написал выше работать не будет

Answer (score 0):

Выравнивание не желательно делать в таблице стилей css ))) Лучше это сделать в коде html требуемой страницы. Для этого в теге `<div align="center"></div>` или аналогично в теге `<table>`.

Или, например, в вашем случае примерно так:

`<H1><img src="../images/картинка.jpg" width="200" height="200" align="middle"/> Текст по центру изображения</H1>`

Либо `<div align="center"><H1><img src="../images/картинка.jpg" width="200" height="200" align="middle"/> Текст по центру изображения</H1></div>`

Или другой вариант:

Сам html код.

```
<div class="imgCenter">
    <img src="картинка.jpg" border="0" width="200" height="200" alt="" />
</div>
```

В свойстве css.

```
.imgCenter { text-align:center;}
```

P.S. уберите лишние пробелы )))

Comment: Как раз нет, вот такое вот выравнивание через `align` уже _deprecated_, желательно наоборот, через CSS.